# Convert cell to double in Matlab

Tags: matlab, double, cell

I have a 2549x28 table *mydata*. Some of the columns are strings, some numbers; however all the values in the table are read as cells. I need to transform some of the cells to doubles. Here is what I did, but it returns two errors.

```
fieldsToModify = {'A','B','C','E','F','G','H', 'I', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'U', 'Z', 'W', 'AB', 'AL', 'AO', 'AR', 'AW'};
for i=1:numel(mydata)
    for j=1:numel(fieldsToModify)
        mydata(i).(fieldsToModify{j}) = str2double(mydata(i).(fieldsToModify{j}));
    end
end
```

Errors that I get:

```
Error using table/subsrefParens (line 14)
You cannot subscript a table using only one subscript. Table subscripting requires both row and variable subscripts.

Error in table/numArgumentsFromSubscript (line 390)
                x = subsrefParens(t,s(1));
```

Comment: You probably need something like `mydata(:,i)` or `mydata(i,:)`, no? Or what is exactly `mydata`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I just added in the description that *mydata* is actually the table I have.

Comment: Do you actually need the loop over `i`? Dont you just want to set some columns by `mydata.(fieldsToModify{j})=...`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak that's true. I was overcomplicating the things. Only the loop over `j` works, in the sense that it converts cells to doubles, but it returns this error `To assign to or create a variable in a table, the number of rows must match the height of the table.`

Comment: Try `str2mat` instead of `str2double`: the latter concatenates the results. Compare both acting on `['12'; '34']`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak with str2mat it works without any error message. Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem:) You might want to consider deleting the question: it depends on whether you expect it to help future readers.

Comment: @AndrasDeak sorry I just realized that actually it seems like it works, but then if I type `class(mydata.OneOfTheField)` it returns `char` and not double o.O

Comment: You're right, sorry. `str2num` is a sure winner, it's more than capable of converting your vector:) (It could even do `str2num('[1:4 5]')`).

Comment: @AndrasDeak just using `str2num` gives me this error: `Error using str2num (line 32)
Requires string or character array input.` I also tried using `str2num(str2mat(mydata.fieldsToModify{j})` but it returns `To assign to or create a variable in a table, the number of rows must match the height of the table.`

Comment: Well aren't you a complicated one;) Your input is a cell, not a character array. If every element of the cell array has the same length (same number of characters), you can use `str2num(cell2mat(...))`. If all else fails, use `cellfun(@(x) str2num(x),mydata.(fieldsToModify{j}))`, but there should be a simpler solution...

Comment: IF you have a cell, then  use `str2num(mydata.(fieldsToModify{j})){:}` to get the contents of the cell. "Should work"

Comment: @AndrasDeak if I use `for j=1:numel(fieldsToModify)
       
       mydata.(fieldsToModify{j}) = str2num(cell2mat(mydata.fieldsToModify{j})));
end` I obtain this error: `Error using cat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. Error in cell2mat (line 83)             m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});` If I do `mydata.(fieldsToModify{j}) =cellfun(@(x) str2num(x),mydata.(fieldsToModify{j}));` I obtain `Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1208, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.` I may be doing something wrong in the code...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I'm not sure about the syntax. If I do that, an error appears: `Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.`

Comment: @dede yep, you're right -- matlab doesn't allow cascaded operations. You'd have to create a variable from `str2num` and then extract the j-th cell contents from that variable.